# Python Import Statements explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am kind of confused on what the import statements does in python so to understand that i have this sample test.py script:

```
def functionA():
    import test
    print("a1")

def functionB():
    print("b")

print("t1")
functionA()
print("m1")
```

When i execute this test.py script using the following command:
`python3 test.py`
I get the following:

```
t1
t1 
a1 
m1 
a1 
m1
```

It would be great if someone can explain to me why i get the following output and what exactly is happening.

Comment: Can you please clarify what parts of ``import`` you understand? What output you would have expected instead? Why are you confused by the output you get?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What does the statement import test do? I was expecting that everytime functionA() is called then it is going to call the script again, executing the script infinitely.

Comment: I've added an answer to what ``import test`` does, and why it seemingly imports the module twice (but not more).

Answer (score 3):

The flow of execution is a little hard to understand. But here it is

> When you execute your file using `python3 test.py` it executes the
>   script whose first line generates `t1`
>
> > Now it calls functionA() which imports your script(**so executing your
> >     script second time**) which gives `t1` then it **calls** **functionA() again**
> >     **but this time test is already imported** so the next line of execution
> >     is `a1`. then we execute line 3 which gives `m1`. Now we come outside
> >     the functionA()'s *(first call)* import and execute `a1`
>
> and **then we exit first functionA() call** and print `m1`

For more info refer this [link](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html)

Comment: It might be worth explaining *why* the module gets executed a second time - something that ``import`` usually does not do.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have added a link for the topic.

Comment: @PrashantNegi if `import test` executes the script how come functionA() doesn't execute infinitely? I was expecting the program to never terminate and keep executing itself. What makes it terminate?

Comment: @YousifDafalla First time **import** is called it register the module/file in the namespace, so if it is already present there(on second call to import), python basically ignores the import

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: `import` loads each module only once per interpreter session. However, the main module is special in that it can be imported in two variants.

---

The `import` statement is responsible for two things:

- loading the target module into the interpreter, and
- binding the module or some of its name in the current scope.

Notably, if the module has already been loaded (it is in `sys.modules`), the module is *not* loaded again. Only the name binding happens in this case.

*This is why importing the module recursively does not rerun its code infinitely.*

---

The main module, that is the initial module run, is special in that it can regularly exist with two variants:

- with the name `__main__`, set automatically by running the module, and
- with its own name such as `test`, set automatically by importing the module.

Notably, these two versions are not identical. [Every module with an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard runs different code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do), and thus achieves different state.

*This is why the `__main__` module can be loaded twice, once under the name `__main__` and once under its own name.*

---

For this code in specific, the sequence is like this:

- Executing `python3 test.py` sets up `test.py` to be imported as `__main__`.
- There is no module `__main__` yet. Python executes `test.py` to create the module.

  - `functionA` and `functionB` are defined,
  - **`print("t1")` is called**,
  - `functionA` is called,

    - `import test` is run,

      - There is no module `test` yet. Python executes `test.py` to create the module.

        - `functionA` and `functionB` are defined,
        - **`print("t1")` is called**,
        - `functionA` is called,
        - `import test` is run,

          - The module `test` already exists (though not completely).
          - Python binds the `test` module to the name `test`.
        - **`print("a1")` is called**,
      - **`print("m1")` is called**,
    - **`print("a1")` is called**,
  - **`print("m1")` is called**,